# SliverAppBar does not float in widget test

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm writing a widget test for my screen and one of the requirements is to have a test for the floating behavior of the `SliverAppBar`. However, I cannot make the test work, because the `SliverAppBar` does not float, although the same code works correctly when run on a real device.

For visualization of the current screen during my test, I compare the screen with a golden file (which does not exist) and run the test with `flutter test --update-goldens` to let the test create the golden file and sure enough the `SliverAppBar` does not appear in the `HomePage_golden_scroll3.png`. The `SliverAppBar` only shows up when scrolling completely back up (i.e. it behaves as if `floating` is `false`.

Since it works just fine on a real device, I'm wondering what is wrong with my test?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            floating: true,
            title: Text('app bar title'),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text('test ' * index)),
              childCount: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  testWidgets('AppBar should hide on scroll', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));
    await expectLater(find.byType(HomePage),
        matchesGoldenFile('HomePage_golden_scroll1.png'));
    expect(find.byType(SliverAppBar), findsOneWidget);
    var scrollableWidget = find.text('test ' * 8);
    var originalPosition = tester.getRect(scrollableWidget);

    // Scroll down.
    final position =
        tester.state<ScrollableState>(find.byType(Scrollable)).position;
    position.jumpTo(500.0);
    await tester.pump();
    await expectLater(find.byType(HomePage),
        matchesGoldenFile('HomePage_golden_scroll2.png'));
    var afterScrollPosition = tester.getRect(scrollableWidget);
    // Make sure the scroll worked, i.e. the view is big enough to scroll.
    expect(afterScrollPosition.top, lessThan(originalPosition.top));
    // Now the AppBar should be hidden.
    expect(find.byType(SliverAppBar), findsNothing);

    // When scrolling up again, the AppBar should be immediately visible
    // again, not only when scrolling up completely.
    position.jumpTo(350);
    await tester.pump();
    await expectLater(find.byType(HomePage),
        matchesGoldenFile('HomePage_golden_scroll3.png'));
    // AppBar should be visible again.
    expect(find.byType(SliverAppBar), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by changing the "position.jumpTo()" to a scroll gesture:

```
await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));
await expectLater(find.byType(HomePage),
    matchesGoldenFile('HomePage_golden.png'));
expect(find.byType(SliverAppBar), findsOneWidget);

final gesture = await tester.startGesture(Offset(0, 300)); 
await gesture.moveBy(Offset(0, -300));
await tester.pump();
await expectLater(find.byType(HomePage),
    matchesGoldenFile('HomePage_golden_scroll.png'));
expect(find.byType(SliverAppBar), findsNothing);

await gesture.moveBy(Offset(0, 100));
await tester.pump();
await expectLater(find.byType(HomePage),
    matchesGoldenFile('HomePage_golden_scroll_back.png'));
expect(find.byType(SliverAppBar), findsOneWidget);
```